# What are the advantages of middleware in Next.js?

Tags: next.js

According to [nextjs documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware)

> Middleware allows you to run code before a request is completed. Then, based on the incoming request, you can modify the response by rewriting, redirecting, modifying the request or response headers, or responding directly.

But aren't they all possible with just getServerSideProps()?

What are the advantages of middleware in Next.js?